# Problem when reordering components with state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component with an input text field (called `SingleItem` in the code below). For storing and updating the value of this text field I am using the `useState` hook.

Now, the parent component can have multiple instances of `SingleItem` and also re-order them.

The problem is that, after they are reordered, it seems that their states are staying in the same order. My understanding is that the hooks rely on the call order so that can explain it.

My question is, what is the proper way of implementing this scenario. I'm thinking that `ReorderComponents` can hold the state for all the `SingleItems` but then passing lambdas for updating can become messy.

```
function SingleItem(props: {item: string}) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<string>(props.item);
    return <div>
        <TextField value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}/>
        <span>Input arg: {props.item}</span>
    </div>;
}

function ReorderComponents() {
    const [items, setItems] = React.useState(["a", "b", "c"]);
    return (
        <div className="App">
            {items.map(number => (
                <SingleItem item={number}/>
            ))}
            <Button variant={'contained'} onClick={() => setItems([...items.reverse()])}>Reverse</Button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is what happens after the button is clicked.

[image]

Comment: You should be getting a console warning about missing a `key` prop  when rendering the SingleItem in the map. They `key` should be persistent and unique, in this case you can just use that value itself `<SingleItem item={number} key={number} />`

Comment: That did it. Thanks @Jayce444 . I thought it was something more obscure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jayce444 answered in the comments. I was missing the `key` property in `SingleItem`

```
<SingleItem item={number} key={number} />
```

Comment: i had the same problem, when using the id of unpersisted elements as key, where the id was not set yet